# jQuery plugin cycle2 caption is not animating up and down during slideshow

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I cant get the animation of the caption / overlay to work. I want the caption to slide up and down from the bottom as the slides go in and out. I tried a bunch of things and I couldn't get it to work. My slides are made up of divs not images. Not sure if I put the HTML for the captions in the right place. I included the caption2 plugin.

**[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w95ya/)**

```
<div class="cycle-slideshow slider"
    data-cycle-slides = "> div"
    data-cycle-fx="scrollHorz"
    data-cycle-timeout="3000"
    data-cycle-caption-plugin="caption2"
    data-cycle-caption-fx-out="slideUp"
    data-cycle-caption-fx-in="slideDown"
        >

<div class="slide1 slide">
    <div class= "innerWrapper" data-cycle-title="Spring">       
        <p class ="slide1text">This is a great div Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatum, unde, vel ratione nulla illum libero fuga placeat corporis molestias quisquam.</p> <img class ="slide1img" src="http://dummyimage.com/300x150/000/fff&text=slide1" alt=""/>
        <br>
            <a href="" class="button">Click More</a>
     </div>
<div class="cycle-overlay">The Redwoods 1</div>
</div>

<div class="slide2 slide">
    <div class = "innerWrapper"  data-cycle-title="Spring" data-cycle-desc="Sonnenberg Gardens">    
        <img class ="slide2img" src="http://dummyimage.com/250x150/000/fff&text=slide2" alt=""/>    
        <p class ="slide2text">Text for slide 2 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellendus, molestias incidunt ab voluptatibus id nemo error delectus sunt impedit illum.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="cycle-caption">Test</div>
<div class="cycle-overlay"></div>
</div>

</div>
```

**[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w95ya/)**

Thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the "test" text from cycle-caption and put it into cycle-overlay so it is consistant with the other slides. then this javascript should get you started:

```
$( '.cycle-slideshow' ).on( 'cycle-after', function(event, optionHash, outgoingSlideEl, incomingSlideEl, forwardFlag) {
    $(incomingSlideEl).find('.cycle-overlay').slideDown();
    $(outgoingSlideEl).find('.cycle-overlay').slideUp();
});
```

you may have to play around with it a bit.
http://jsfiddle.net/w95ya/1/

Check this link to see what events you can listen for: http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/api/